# Can't make maling via dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary, email, outlook

**Trying to send files to diff recipients, but can only a singl one, otherwise - error.**
if del any of dictionary mail can be sent w/o any problem but not with loop for several dictionary conditions

```
from win32com.client.gencache import EnsureDispatch
from win32com.client import constants


outlook = EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
mail = outlook.CreateItem(constants.olMailItem)

PATH = 'C:/Users/aoivanov/OneDrive - ArcelorMittal/Documents/MARKETING/Consolidated_stock/'


def send_mail(mail_list, list_file, message):
    mail.Subject = 'Consolidated stock'
    mail.Body = message
    attachment_list = []

    for i in mail_list:
        samplegrp1 = mail.Recipients.Add(i)
        samplegrp1.Type = constants.olTo
        mail.Recipients.ResolveAll()

    for file in list_file:
        attachment = PATH + file
        attachment_list.append(attachment)

    for attachment in attachment_list:
        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)

    mail.Send()


list_file_mht = ['MHT.xlsx', 'FREE_STOCK.xlsx']
mail_list_mht = ['aaa@arcelormittal.com', 'bbb@arcelormittal.com', 'ccc@gmail.com']
message_mht = 'text1'

list_file_vikant = ['VIKANT.xlsx']
mail_list_vikant = ['xxx@arcelormittal.com']
message_vikant = 'text2'

list_dic = [{'list_file': list_file_mht, 'mail_list': mail_list_mht, 'message': message_mht},
            {'list_file': list_file_vikant, 'mail_list': mail_list_vikant, 'message': message_vikant}]


for index, value in enumerate(list_dic):
    send_mail(list_dic[index].get('mail_list'), list_dic[index].get('list_file'), list_dic[index].get('message'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Recipients.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients.add) method creates a new recipient in the `Recipients` collection and accepts the name of the recipient as a parameter - it can be a string representing the display name, the alias, or the full SMTP email address of the recipient.

```
for i in mail_list:
        samplegrp1 = mail.Recipients.Add(i)
        samplegrp1.Type = constants.olTo
        mail.Recipients.ResolveAll()
```

It is not clear what value is passed to the `Add` method.

Also, there is no need to use the `ResolveAll` method in the loop. Instead, you can use the `Resolve` method of the Recipient class instead.

```
for i in mail_list:
        samplegrp1 = mail.Recipients.Add(i)
        samplegrp1.Type = constants.olTo
        samplegrp1.Resolve()
```

Comment: Thanks for help. It's still show the same error.  The code with Add methon was found on internet. If I use this code for 1 recipient or for the list - it's ok but if I try to use for list more then one dictionary - I get error

Comment: That is for a single recipient. You need to repeat it for each recipient.